# Facebook PHP SDK 4: FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper Issue

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

Im using the FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper method to get the session (Im logged with Javascript API) but is not working fine. I need to reload the page to get the data.

And it seems like after a while the session expires and I need to reload the page again to get the session.

Any hint?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the JavaScript SDK, the cookie is set after the user has logged in, which is inaccessible to the PHP code since it was set after the PHP code was loaded. The PHP script needs to be re-loaded after the JS SDK has set the cookie.

This is the way JavaScript and PHP behave together, as PHP is server-side and rendered before the JavaScript code (which is client-side) has executed.